# Why any electric field doesn't exist outside the conductive spherical shell?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

[image]

The conductive spherical shell(green one) and the conductive sphere are given(blue one).

The inner sphere is charged with $Q~$ and the outer shell is grounded and not charged.

$V_{\text{a}}:=\text{potential at the inner surface of the shell}$

$V_{\text{b}}:=\text{potential at the outer surface of the shell}$

$E_{r}:=\text{electric field outside the shell}$

The description says that $V_{\text{a}}=V_{\text{b}}=E_{r}=0$

It is obvious that $V_{\text{a}}=V_{\text{b}}=0$ however the problem for me is to get $E_{r}=0$

For instance if we apply Gauss law and include the shell with the sphere then the below equation must be held.

$$\text{sum of electric fields}=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_{0}}$$

What should I consider for next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the outer sphere is grounded, so its potential difference with everything around you - assuming you are in a safely earthed environment - is zero. The outer sphere is not uncharged however. When it was connected to earth a charge -Q flowed onto its inner surface. That is another way of explaining why there is no field outside the shell: there is no net charge inside it.